# Div height (vw units?) not working in IOS safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBWvMX

Expected behaviour is that at large window sizes the yellow and red divs are next to each other and in smaller they stack on top and are scrollable.

This works on Chrome, Firefox, IE on PC.

This works for Chrome, Firefox, Safari on Mac.

This works for Chrome on Android.

**This does not work for Chrome or Safari on IOS devices!!!**

Instead on IOS devices this is being rendered as one massive div far too tall for the viewport. The other div is not appearing at all.

I've tried a combination of things and the only way I've had some slight success is using @media queries in the css. I'd rather not resort to doing this as I can't guarantee to support every device.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="app">
    <div class="row" id="bg">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="pic">
        <div class="leftlayer-gradient hidden-md hidden-lg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="details">
        <div class="rightlayer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#pic, #details {
  height: 100vh;
}

#details {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
}

#pic {
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
}

.rightlayer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftlayer-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The issue was nothing to do with the viewport or compatibility with browsers/OS.

I was using forwarding with masking from my DNS provider and it they were just forwarding to the site through an iframe (yuck!).

If you're with GoDaddy you may have the same issue.